# glTexSubImage2D() and glGetTextureImageEXT() used instead of GPUDirect

Tags: opengl, gpu, nvidia, video-card, gpudirect

My setup:

- NVIDIA Quadro p6000 (used for [GPUDirect](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpudirect))
- AJA video card (SDI feed from camera and SDI output to the TV)

I am trying to figure out what is the purpose of GPUDirect (in my specific case) if I can achieve the same amount of copying and the same performance using `glTexSubImage2D()` to fill the GPU texture with any system memory and `glGetTextureImageEXT()` to get the texture data from the GPU back to any part of system memory.

Comment: What is "GPU Direct"?

Comment: @NicolBolas: Nvidia's marketing term (AMD uses "DirectGMA") for bus mastered transfers between VRAM and other PCIe devices,

Comment: It seems that using GPU Direct for AJA and GPU communication is completely avoiding the system memory. That means that glTexSubImage2D() and glGetTextureImageEXT() are less efficient I guess.

Comment: How is this related to OpenGL? From the documentation on NVIDIA website I see this tech targets CUDA.

Comment: The only example from AJA card SDK for GPU Direct is using the OpenGL. I have contacted the AJA people and they have told me that using OpenGL is highly recommended. I guess you have to interop it then to the separated CUDA environment? I am not sure...